# Woocommerce disable checkout on specific day

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm searching for a plugin or code snippet to disable the checkout of one of my clients webshops to disable the checkout on a specific day of the week. I couldn't talk it out of their head so it should be done. I found the advanced checkout plugin but found out it is horrible broken. I tried to find a code-snippet for WooCommerce for it but I failed in my search. Anybody has an idea of an existing snippet or one that is similar to the action I want to achieve so I could alter it a little and use it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: i'm trying to write my own snippet and this is what I achieved so far:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'disable_checkout_sunday' );
function disable_checkout_sunday(){
   if (date(D) == "Sun"){
    remove__action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment');
  }
}
```

This is something I have improvised but I'm not sure if this would work. Also, isn't there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You might try this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-hours-scheduler-for-woocommerce/). It able to schedule your open time in terms of day & hours. Then you can set bar to notify user when your store close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach in my opinion would be to redirect the cart and checkout pages to a static page with user friendly message.

This shows how to [get Various WooCommerce Page URLs](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-woocommerce-page-urls/), you can hook a function to `init`, that function will:

- See if the current URL matches the URL of the checkout or cart pages
- If so, it will `wp_redirect` to your static page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Haven't thought about this myself but this seems like a way better solution. Will try this evening to implement this and as soon as I have it will post the result.